# How to upload docs to signed AWS S3? What is bucket and objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get a pre-signed `AWS s3 url` to upload documents. How do I upload a file to this pre-signed url? Do I need to create a bucket (I don't know what a bucket is)? Do I need credentials for S3 to upload a document using a pre-signed url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a file to an S3 pre-signed URL using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
curl -T dog.png "<pre-signed url here>"
```

Yes, the bucket needs to exist in advance.

No, you don't need additional credentials.

Comment: I am uploading file through code in c#. However, I am getting exception says `Unable to find credential`.

Comment: There's a C# example (method name: UploadObject) of how to upload a file to a pre-signed URL at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html.

Comment: I have used the same code for using signed url to upload pdf but getting exception as `Unable to find credential`.

Comment: Can I check whether the file uploaded using signed url? or how I can get url of uploaded file using signed aws s3 url?

Comment: No, you cannot use the pre-signed url that you used to upload the file to subsequently test for its existence. If your PUT code is correct and it returned no errors then the file will be there. Other ways to verify that an object actually exists in S3 include using the AWS console or the awscli. By the way, you're not providing much helpful information when you report the "Unable to find credential" exception. What API call were you making that resulted in this exception, for example?

Comment: using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
                {
                    UploadObject(url);

                }  `using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) {` this line was causing those exception when I remove this line and call only to upload that working. Anyway does that matter if not be there?

Comment: If you need to make AWS API calls then you need an AmazonS3Client and to create an AmazonS3Client you need AWS credentials. The documentation on how to provide credentials is pretty clear. That said, you do not need to make AWS API calls if all you are doing is putting a file to a pre-signed URL -- that is done using native HTTP function, not AWS API calls.